# Python: Activate window in OS X

Tags: python, macos, applescript

I'm running `OS X 10.11`, and I have created a web scraper using `Python` and `Selenium`. The scraper uses `Firefox` as the browser to collect data.

The Firefox window must remain active at all critical steps, for the scraper to work.

When I leave the computer with Firefox as the active window, when I return I often find that the active window focus has changed to something else. Some process is stealing the window focus.

Is there a way that I can programatically tell the OS to activate the Firefox window? If so, I can tell the script to do that before every critical action in the script.

Preferably, this is something that I would like to achieve using Python. But launching a secondary `AppleScript` to do this specific task may also be a solution.

**Note:** Atm, I'm not looking at rewriting my script to use a headless browser – just to make it work by forcing active window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use AppleEvents in python importing the module `Carbon`. Here an example of an python script activating FireFox by its bundle identifier.

```python
from Carbon import AppleEvents 
from Carbon import AE
target = AE.AECreateDesc(AppleEvents.typeApplicationBundleID, "org.mozilla.FireFox")
activateEvent  = AE.AECreateAppleEvent( 'misc', 'actv', target, AppleEvents.kAutoGenerateReturnID, AppleEvents.kAnyTransactionID)
activateEvent.AESend(AppleEvents.kAEWaitReply, AppleEvents.kAENormalPriority, AppleEvents.kAEDefaultTimeout)
```

Comment: This saved me. Thanks!

Comment: What if i have several Firefox windows open, how to activate a particular one?

Answer (score 2):

`tell application "Firefox" to activate`

is the way to do it in AppleScript